# Microsoft vbscript runtime error object doesnt support this property:WScript.CreatObject

Tags: wscript.shell

Basically when I run the .vbs file it gives me the error from line one:Object doesn't support this property or method:"WScript.CreatObject"

```
mySecret = inputbox("enter text to be encoded")
mySecret = StrReverse(mySecret)
x.Run "%windir%\notepad"
wscript.sleep 1000
x.sendkeys encoded(mySecret)

function encode(s)
For i = 1 To Len(s)
newtxt = Mid(s,i,1)
newtxt = Chr(Asc(newtxt)+5)
coded = coded & newtxt
Next
encode = coded
End Function
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSY79.jpg
```

Comment: It would help if you actually posted the code that errors out. Maybe it's a typo like "CreatObject" (missing "e").

Comment: I added the link to a screenshot of the error message

Comment: As I said. Typo. It's `CreateObject` not `CreatObject`.

Comment: Ohh that's why, sorry for the trouble of asking because I can't check the spelling myself when I need to.